# A Person class containing a list of Persons

Tags: c#

What do you guys think about this? I myself think it is pretty usefull, But how does it look from an OOP perspective?

Here's an example class

```
public class Person
{
    private string firstName, lastName;
    private int id;
    private static int statId;
    private static List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    public Person(string firstName,string lastName)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;

        //Like this, everytime a new object of Person is created, the ID will be the id of the last created object +1
        id = statId;
        statId++;

        //Everytime you create a new instance of this class, it will be added to the list
        persons.Add(this);

    }
    public static Person GetPersonById(int id)
    {
        foreach(Person per in persons)
        {
            if (per.ID == id)
                return per;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
    }

    public static List<Person> GetPersons()
    {
        return persons;
    }    
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }
    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, aside from being able to use this class to store persons, you can also use some methods like `GetPersonById` and `GetPersons` / the `PersonList` property without instantiating it, and whenever you do instantiate it to make a new person, it automatically adds it to the list

Comment: Welcome to code review, it is a good first question. @t3chb0t Made some good points.

Comment: @stafan What's the problem solved by having static accessors to get `Person` objects by their ID? Seems like a hack to communicate between classes without designing in proper channels for sending `Person` objects around.

Comment: Also, `persons` would be a lot more appropriately modelled by a `Dictionary<int, Person>` that maps `Person` `id`s to `Person` objects

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But how does it look from an OOP perspective?

Not very good because it combines multiple responsibilities in a single class.

- the one of a **data** object as the `Person` is clear, I guess. The other two are
- the **repository** represented by

> ```
> private static List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
>
> public static Person GetPersonById(int id)
> {
>     foreach(Person per in persons)
>     {
>         if (per.ID == id)
>             return per;
>     }
>     return null;
> }
>
> public static List<Person> GetPersons()
> {
>     return persons;
> }
> ```

- and the **factory** represented by

> ```
> private static int statId;
> statId++;
> ```

This means that the `Person` should actually be **three** classes.

On top of all this you cannot test it because the *nested* factory is a static one and if you try to write a test validating the `statId++` you couldn't because you cannot verfiy that it'll do `+1` to the last id because if any other test executes at the same time the result might actually be `+2` or even more. You also cannot verify that it correctly adds the new instance to the list because agian, if any tests execute at the same time you could have more then one object added to the list.

---

> ```
> id = statId;
> statId++;
> ```

I find this is not how the id increment should be implemented. `statId` should not be the *next* index but the last one. What if you decide to add a property like `LastId`? You'd have to calculate it first with `statId - 1` - ugly. Instead use the prefix `++` like `id = ++statId` and start with `int statId = -1;` that is usually considered as na *invalid* index in many APIs. Then the `LastId` property could just be `LastId => statId;`.

Comment: Thanks! I had an itch saying its probably not really good :P

Comment: Putting a general people accessor inside a 'person' seems really counter-intuitive. That would make me think there must be a better way. The static list makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @David Neither are good and neither are used in this answer.

Comment: @eurotrash My comment was supporting the answer's logic. I should have written more clearly.

Answer (score 2):

@t3chb0t answer, all good.

I suggest yet a 4th class - `People`. Why? First it supports the idea of a DSL - Domain Specific Language. Meaning, write code in terms of your problem domain. You want to express "People" not "List". Second we take advantage of .net collection functionality but expose that functionality in people (DSL) terms. Third we can limit client access to the `List<Person>` so we allow only those things we want for People. And finally it is a good application of the single responsibility principle.

To limit client access I show `People` wrapping a `List<person>` rather than inheriting from it or another .net class. Note that MS recommends inheriting from `System.Collections.ObjectModel.CollectionBase`:

> This base class is provided to make it easier for implementers to create a custom collection. Implementers are encouraged to extend this base class instead of creating their own.

That would be good if you need to do lots of collective stuff - you gotta love all those extension methods! But here I want to demonstrate encapsulation.

In the `Person` class override `Equals()`. This will make `List<person>.Contains()`, for example, do *identity equality*. And you want that because you have a unique Id built into `Person`.

```
public class People {
    protected List<person> ThePeople { get; set; }
    protected PeoplePool Repository { get; set; }

    public People(PeoplePool repository) { 
       ThePeople = new List<person>(); 

       if ( repository == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(" Database is missing ");

       Repository = repository;
    }

    public void AddPerson( Person anotherPerson ) {
       anotherPerson ?? return;

       if ( ThePeople.Contains(anotherPerson)) return;

       anotherPerson.Id = repository.GetNextId();
       ThePeople.Add( anotherPerson );
    }

    public void AddPerson( int personId ) {
       AddPerson( Repository.GetById( personId ) );
    }

    public Person GetById( int personId ) {
        return ThePeople.FirstOrDefault( x => x.Id == personId );
    }

    public People GetByLastName( string LastName ) {
        LastName = LastName ?? string.Empty;
        People TheSmits = new People( Repository );
        TheSmits.AddRange( ThePeople.FindAll( x => x.LastName.ToLower() == LastName.ToLower() ));
        return TheSmits;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but I have one question... I'm a little bit confused about the `PeoplePool`... why do you pass it via the constructor and then don't use it? ;-)

Comment: Its a debatable design point I suppose. The accepted answer mentions a repository so I put it in there. And it is used, in a `AddPerson` overload. I.E. Oh look! 2 methods that "seem the same" but are very different underneath; you know, like, encapsulation!

Comment: By _not used_ I mean you didn't assingn the `repository` to anything but checking whether it's null. I guess overlooked? Or am I missing some trick?

Comment: Obtusity is the lesser part of debugging.